# Find only GUIDs in file - Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, wildcards

I have a file that might contain GUIDs (their [canonical textual representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format)).

I want to do an action for each GUID in the file. It might contain any number of GUIDs.

I have already a file ready for reading. How do I spot the GUIDS?

I know I need to use `while read FILENAME`

An example of my file :

```
GUIDs
--------------------------------------
cf6e328c-c918-4d2f-80d3-71ecaf09bf7b
91d523b0-4926-456e-a9d2-ade713f5b07f
(2 rows)
// THERE IS AN EMPTY LINE HERE AFTER NUMBER OF ROWS
```

Comment: Post your sample file.

Comment: You're looking for any digit(s) from 0 to 10k, in any format? Or what exactly

Comment: I wrote a file as example

Comment: What's the action you want to perform? It alters the possible solution

Comment: I need to run a command and then wait 5 seconds

Comment: Your example file shows at most one guid per line, taking what appears to be the entire line. Is that correct? Could anything other then a guid and the final "(X rows)" message appear below the line of dashes?

Comment: @roaima I have added an example file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the GNU implementation of `grep` (or compatible):

```
<your-file grep -Ewo '[[:xdigit:]]{8}(-[[:xdigit:]]{4}){3}-[[:xdigit:]]{12}' |
  while IFS= read -r guid; do
    your-action "$guid"
    sleep 5
  done
```

Would find those GUIDs wherever they are in the input (and provided they are  neither preceded nor followed by *word characters*).

GNU `grep` has a `-o` option that prints the non-empty matches of the regular expression.

`-w` is another non-standard extension coming I believe from SysV to match on whole words only. It matches only if the matched text is between a transition between a non-word and word character and one between a word and non-word character (where word characters are alphanumerics or underscore). That's to guard against matching on things like:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

The rest is standard POSIX syntax. Note that `[[:xdigit:]]` matches on ABCDEF as well. You can replace it with `[0123456789abcdef]` if you want to match only lower case GUIDs.

Comment: Can you please explain? What is that "<" in the beginning ?

Also - what is GNU tools ? Can we assume my file name is GUIDS.TXT ?

Comment: Also - what is GNU tools ?

Comment: @MathEnthusiast, see edit. The GNU project is an effort by the Free Software Foundation to provide with a FLOSS reimplementation of Unix. Some people confuse it with Linux as GNU systems generally use Linux as their kernel. They have written extended versions of the Unix utilities (like `grep` here) which support extensions like that `-o` and `\<` (`\<` was in SysV `grep` before GNU's). GNU utilities are now more common than the original versions, and many other non-GNU implementations have copied some of the GNU extensions. In particular, `-o` is found in many other implementations.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, how do you guard against matching `cf6e328c-c918-4d2f-80d3-71ecaf09bf7b-91d523b0-4926-456e-a9d2-ade713f5b07f`?  (i.e. some non-guid thing that looks like two guids joined by a hyphen)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: What edge-case are you guarding for with the `IFS= read -r` vs. a simple `read`?

Comment: @Noach, it's more that `IFS= read -r` is the syntax to read a line. `-r` is not strictly necessary here given that we can guarantee that the input won't contain backspace but doesn't harm (and helps wrt performance). `IFS=` is needed unless you can guarantee that the current value of IFS doesn't contain hex digits.

Comment: @Noach, that code _explicitely_ (by using `\<`) considers `cf6e328c-c918-4d2f-80d3-71ecaf09bf7b-91d523b0-4926-456e-a9d2-ade713f5b07f` as two guids joined by a hyphen. I would argue that if you find that somewhere, it's most likely what it is.

Answer (score 3):

While I love Regular Expressions, I prefer to **avoid over-specifying**.
For this particular data set (known data format, one GUID per line, plus header and footer), I'd just strip out the header/footers:

```
$ cat guids.txt | egrep -v 'GUIDs|--|rows|^$' |
    while read guid ; do
      some_command "$guid"
      sleep 5
    done
```

Alternatively, I'd grep out the lines I want, but also keep the regexp as simple as possible for the current data set:

`egrep '^[0-9a-f-]{36}$'`